# Edit data into JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a simple JSON

```
{
    "users":[
        {
          "last result": "2%",
          "login": "user",
          "password": "1",
          "id": "1"
        }
            ]
}
```

I want to add new user and then delete user by ID.

for example:

i want to add this:

```
{"id":"2", "login": "admin", "password":"22", "last result": "10%"}
```

after my action, json should look like this:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
          "last result": "2%",
          "login": "1user",
          "password": "1",
          "id": "2"
        },
        {
          "id":"2", 
          "login": "admin", 
          "password":"22", 
           "last result": "10%"
        }
            ]
}
```

I've tried this:

```
...
user = {"id": 2, "login": "admin", "password": "1", "last result": "2%"}
def save_data_to_json(user):
    jsonFile = open("auth.json", "r+")
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()
    data["users"] = user
    jsonFile = open("auth.json", "a+")
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
    jsonFile.close()
```

But after this, my JSON looks a little bit strange:

```
{
    "users":[
        {
          "last result": "2%",
          "login": "1user",
          "password": "1",
          "id": "2"
        }
            ]
}{"users": {"id": 2, "login": "1user", "password": "1", "last result": "2%"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should open `auth.json` with `w` and not with `a+`. When you open with `a+` it means you append your output to it instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import json
user = {"id": 2, "login": "admin", "password": "1", "last result": "2%"}
def save_data_to_json(user):
    jsonFile = open("/tmp/auth.json", "r+")
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()
    data["users"].append(user)
    jsonFile = open("/tmp/auth.json", "w")
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
    jsonFile.close()

save_data_to_json(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is has a key 'users' which is a *collection* of user objects. In your code though, you are doing `data['users'] = user` which is just replacing the existing collection with your new user, not adding to it:

```
>>> s = '''{
...     "users":[
...         {
...           "last result": "2%",
...           "login": "user",
...           "password": "1",
...           "id": "1"
...         }
...             ]
... }'''
>>> o = json.loads(s)
>>> o['users']
[{u'last result': u'2%', u'login': u'user', u'password': u'1', u'id': u'1'}]
>>> user = {"id": 2, "login": "admin", "password": "1", "last result": "2%"}
>>> o['users'] = user
>>> o['users']
{'last result': '2%', 'login': 'admin', 'password': '1', 'id': 2}
```

Note now how the object has changed. Instead of it being a collection of users, its now just one user object. This will have an impact on whatever application is reading this file.

Instead you need to do this:

```
>>> o['users'].append(user)
>>> o['users']
[{u'last result': u'2%', u'login': u'user', u'password': u'1', u'id': u'1'}, {'last result': '2%', 'login': 'admin', 'password': '1', 'id': 2}]
```

Now you have two users in the 'users' collection, to delete a user by their value:

```
>>> o['users'] = [u for u in o['users'] if u['login'] != 'admin']  # Get rid of the admin
>>> o['users']
[{u'last result': u'2%', u'login': u'user', u'password': u'1', u'id': u'1'}]
```

Then you can convert the object back to json and write it out.

Putting all this together, your code is:

```
with open('auth.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data['users'].append(user)
# If you want to delete
data['users'] = [u for u in o['users'] if u['login'] != 'admin']  # Get rid of the admin

# Write it back

with open('auth.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```